# how to upload multiple files using flask in python

Tags: python, flask

Here is my code for multiple files upload:

**HTML CODE:**

```
Browse <input type="file" name="pro_attachment1" id="pro_attachment1" multiple>
```

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
pro_attachment = request.files.getlist('pro_attachment1')

for upload in pro_attachment:
    filename = upload.filename.rsplit("/")[0]
    destination = os.path.join(application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    print "Accept incoming file:", filename
    print "Save it to:", destination
    upload.save(destination)
```

But it uploads a single file instead of multiple files.

Comment: What is the length of the pro_attachment list?

Comment: user can select multiple files.length is according to they select the files

Answer (score 16):

### How to

In the template, you need to add `mulitple` attribute in upload input:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photos" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in view function, the uploaded files can get as a list through `request.files.getlist('photos')`. Loop this list and call [save()](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save) method on each item ([werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)) will save them at given path:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = '/the/path/to/save'

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        for f in request.files.getlist('photo'):
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], f.filename))
        return 'Upload completed.'
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

Furthermore, you may need to use [secure_filename()](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) to *clean* filename:

```
# ...
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
# ...
    for f in request.files.getlist('photo'):
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
        # ...
```

You can also generate a random filename with this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992275/5511849).

### Full demo

View:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)  
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = '/the/path/to/save'

@main.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and 'photo' in request.files:
        for f in request.files.getlist('photo'):
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
        return 'Upload completed.'
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

Form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed, FileRequired

class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    photo = FileField('Image', validators=[
        FileRequired(),
        FileAllowed(photos, 'Image only!')
    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.photo(multiple="multiple") }}
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

### More

For better upload experience, you can try [Flask-Dropzone](https://github.com/greyli/flask-dropzone).

Comment: How do I check that the user actually uploaded a file?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks perfect. 
I think the only mistake your making is splitting and taking the first value.
And also i dont know about the rsplit(), but the split() works perfect for me.

**HTML CODE**

```
<input id="upload_img" name="zip_folder"  type="file" multiple  webkitdirectory  >
```

**PYTHON CODE**

```
@app.route('/zipped',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def zipped():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.getlist("zip_folder")
        print f
        for zipfile in f:
            filename = zipfile.filename.split('/')[1]
            print zipfile.filename.split('/')[1]
            zipfile.save(os.path.join(app.config['ZIPPED_FILE'], filename))
        return render_template('final.html')
```