# Create IDs in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management

I am a beginner in python.
The program I want to create in python, allows me to take photos and save the photos with a unique id. When I run the program again, the program continues to take pictures and save them with different ids to the previous ones.
Please help me how I can create variable id. Do I have to make a memory allocation?
The python version is: 2.7.9
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want so save files with unique file names, you can look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961509/python-how-to-create-a-unique-file-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really trying to do is create a database. Take a look at the guide for [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html) (Python Standard Library).

Comment: Hello,thank you for answering me. How can I save pictures to database in this case? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I did it with sqlite3 and it works. Thank you so much